# Setup IntelliJ IDEA 12 with Play2 and framework sources (java)

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12, its Play2.0 plugin for a Java project.
Unfortunately Play 2 (2.1.4 at this time) does not ship with the sources for its dependencies, and running `idea with-sources=yes` only downloads the *project's dependencies* sources.

So far I've had to manually download the source jars and attach them whenever I needed them.
Of course I have to redo this every time the Play framework is updated.

Is there any better way, either within play, which I would prefer, or with an external solution?
Unfortunately IDEA's "Search in internet..." button usually doesn't work, most likely because it's looking on the wrong respositories. I suspect it is trying to use the Maven settings with the configured Nexus repos, but AFAIK Maven central is not in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as running `update-classifiers` in the Play console and then regenerating the project files.
I wish this would be done automatically, but apparently it is too obvious to sbt users.